# Perl - Stock ticker error : Undefined fetch-method

Tags: perl

I'm working on stock ticker program for my class. This program should read ticker list from a file, fetch information using [Finance::Quote](http://search.cpan.org/~ecocode/Finance-Quote-1.37/lib/Finance/Quote.pm) module and display the result on to the screen. When I ran my program, I received error as follow:
`Undefined fetch-method (ticker)
 passed to Finance::Quote::fetch at filename.pl line 56.`

I have searched for this error's cause all day, but I can't find any answer that help me to understand the problem. Can anyone can help?

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#
use strict;
use Finance::Quote;

# Set preferred currency
my $CURRENCY = "CNY";   

# Assign file name to scalar variable, read file, and then assign 
# to an array
my $techticker = "techticker.txt";
open (FH, "< $techticker") or die $!;
my @STOCKS = <FH>;
print @STOCKS, "\n";
close FH or die "Cannot close $techticker: $!"; 

# Define the format : label, style formatting, width of the field
my @labels = (["name",  "%24s",  15],
           ["date",  "%11s",  17], 
           ["time",  "%8s",  10],
           ["last",  "%8.2f",  8],
           ["high",  "%8.2f",  8], 
           ["low",   "%8.2f",  8],
           ["close", "%8.2f",  8], 
           ["volume","%10d",  10]);

# Seconds between refresh
my $REFRESH = 120;  

# --- END CONFIG SECTION ---

my $quoter = Finance::Quote->new();
my $clear  = `clear`;           # So we can clear the screen.

# Build our header.

my $header = "\t\t\tMEGA CAPITAL TECHNOLOGY COMPANY STOCK REPORT" .    ($CURRENCY ? " ($CURRENCY)" : "") ."\n\n";

foreach my $tuple (@labels) {
    my ($name, undef, $width) = @$tuple;
    $header .= sprintf("%".$width."s",uc($name));
 }

$header .= "\n".("-"x85)."\n";

# --- END HEADER SECTION ---

# Set default currency.
$quoter->set_currency($CURRENCY) if $CURRENCY;  


for (;;) {  # For ever.
    print $clear,$header;

    foreach my $stockset (@STOCKS) {
        my ($exchange, @symbols) = $stockset;           # I think the problem is here
        my %info = $quoter->fetch($exchange,@symbols);

        foreach my $symbol (@symbols) {
            next unless $info{$symbol,"success"}; # Skip failures.
            foreach my $tuple (@labels) {
                my ($label,$format) = @$tuple;
                printf $format,$info{$symbol,$label};
            }
            print "\n";
        }
    }

    sleep($REFRESH);
}
```

Update:
Just fixed my code, I should extract my data and assign it to $exchange and @symbols outside the "foreach" loop. Here are the fixed code:

```
my $techticker = "techticker.txt";
open (FH, "< $techticker") or die $!;
my @symbols = <FH>;
chomp @symbols;
my $exchange = shift @symbols;

close FH or die "Cannot close $techticker: $!";
```

...

```
my %info = $quoter->fetch($exchange,@symbols);

for (;;) {  # For ever.
    print $clear,$header;

    foreach my $symbol (@symbols) {
        next unless $info{$symbol,"success"}; # Skip failures.
        foreach my $tuple (@labels) {
            my ($label,$format) = @$tuple;
            printf $format,$info{$symbol,$label};
        }
        print "\n";
    }

    sleep($REFRESH);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my @STOCKS = <FH>;
...snip...
foreach my $stockset (@STOCKS) {
    my ($exchange, @symbols) = $stockset;    # I think the problem is here
```

Indeed, I believe you are correct. `@STOCKS` is an array of simple strings. They won't automatically transform into `$exchange` and `@symbols`. Your code is this equivalent of doing

```
my ($exchange, @symbols) = "the rain in spain falls mainly in the plain";
```

in which case `$exchange` gets Eliza's entire practice phrase, and @symbols is completely empty.

Try looking up the `split()` function, `perldoc -f split`. I suspect that's what you want, but I don't know what the data looks like inside of your techticker.txt.

Comment: it's a simple data: usa\nAAPL\nFB\nGOOG\nMSFT. I will try to use split, I will let you know if it works. Thanks.

Comment: split didn't work, I use chomp instead and change the extraction sequence. It fixed the problem :)